# Android: storing translations to local cache

Tags: android, json, performance, sharedpreferences, translation

I am making an android application with multilingual support. But instead of defining different string folders in my resources (ie. strings-en), I have to acquire the translations via a HTTP GET request from the server. I only make this request on the initial run of the application and of course later when updating is necessary(but naturally we do not expect updates to be happening all that often, in meanings of translations).

The server responds with a string that contains a JSON Object. I then proceed to parse that string and acquire the necessary translations (ie. "no_data": "No data.").

So my question is as follows: what is the most efficient way for me to handle these translations? When I'm building my views, I have to acquire translations for different part of the UI. Is parsing that JSON at that moment (usually in onCreate() since I have a lot of fragments) even an efficient way to do it? What if I would store each translation entry as an entry to SharedPreferences (ie. putString("no_data", "No data.")? Would that take up too much storage space? Also I'm working with 2.3.3 so using a Set is not an option, since it's API level 11.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up parsing JSON and storing translations to SharedPreferences in the form of key and value, where keys differ by language tags (ie. trans_**en**_log_out or trans_**da**_log_out). It's fast and doesn't use too much space within the application.